# Configure AWS Cloudfront Path Pattern workaround for Regular Expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

From what it appears, Cloudfront Path Pattern doesn't support complete regex.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to separate the requests `/[a-z]*` from the requests `/[a-z]/.+` to different origins.

So, a request `/page` must have a different behavior from `/page/something`. And I can't seem to figure out a way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `/*/*` earlier in the path order (lower sequence number) and `/*` later in the list.

CloudFront uses first match, not best match and `/*/*` won't match anything without at least one slash in the middle of the path.  Of course, the default behavior may make the second entry unnecessary.